# Showing/Hiding PKToolPicker with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, pencilkit

I am having two issues using `PKToolPicker` with SwiftUI. The first issue is that once I draw on the canvas view, toggling the visibility of the `PKToolPicker` doesn't make it go away. The second issue is that sometimes the `PKToolPicker` doesn't go away when dismissing the view. Here is my code:

```
struct CanvasView: UIViewRepresentable {
  final class Coordinator: NSObject {
    @Binding var canvasView: PKCanvasView

    let canvasDidChange: (PKCanvasView) -> Void
    let picker: PKToolPicker

    init(
      canvasView: Binding<PKCanvasView>,
      canvasDidChange: @escaping (PKCanvasView) -> Void,
      picker: PKToolPicker
    ) {
      _canvasView = canvasView
      self.canvasDidChange = canvasDidChange
      self.picker = picker
    }

    deinit {
      picker.setVisible(false, forFirstResponder: canvasView)
      picker.removeObserver(canvasView)
    }
  }

  @Binding var canvasView: PKCanvasView
  @Binding var showToolPicker: Bool

  let canvasDidChange: (PKCanvasView) -> Void

  let picker = PKToolPicker()

  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(canvasView: $canvasView, canvasDidChange: canvasDidChange, picker: picker)
  }

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
    canvasView.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: .black, width: 10)
    #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    canvasView.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
    #endif
    canvasView.delegate = context.coordinator
    picker.addObserver(canvasView)
    canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()
    return canvasView
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    picker.setVisible(showToolPicker, forFirstResponder: canvasView)
  }
}
```

I've verified that `updateUIView` is called when changing `showToolPicker` and that `showToolPicker` has the correct value. Unfortunately, once I draw on the canvas `showToolPicker` being true or false does make it go away. Further, if `showToolPicker` is false, it appears as though the `PKToolPicker` is no longer attached to the canvas view and changing the pen tool in the `PKToolPicker` has no effect.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a SwiftUI/PencilKit bug?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to change the visibility of the tool picker after the canvas had been drawn on; however, moving the some of the tool picker logic to `onAppear` and `onDisappear` solved the issue with the tool picker continuing to show after dismissing the view. Here are the main changes:

```
private final class DrawingManager: ObservableObject {
  let toolPicker = PKToolPicker()
  var canvasView: PKCanvasView?

  func register(_ canvasView: PKCanvasView) {
    self.canvasView = canvasView
    toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvasView)
    toolPicker.addObserver(canvasView)
  }

  func unregister() {
    guard let canvasView else {
      return
    }
    toolPicker.setVisible(false, forFirstResponder: canvasView)
    toolPicker.removeObserver(canvasView)
    self.canvasView = nil
  }
}

struct DrawingView: View {
  ...
 
  @StateObject private var drawingManager = DrawingManager()
  @State private var canvasView = PKCanvasView()

  ...

  var body: some View {
    <VIEW CODE>
      .onAppear {
        drawingManager.register(canvasView)
      }
      .onDisappear {
        drawingManager.unregister()
      }
    }
  }
```